# Refresh 2 Gridview using 1 button asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Is it  possible to refresh two Gridview after an update using a single button? The source of my Gridviews are different stored procedures.

Comment: Yes you can in your button there just rebind 2 gridview...

Comment: If you want someone to help you with the code, please edit your question and add the relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to notify the grid that the object had a modification. To do that, Make your ViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged and you can then notify when the property changes (the data structures holding your datas). The grid will then be refreshed

Answer (score 0):

in your button click call the update stored procedure first and after that you can call the fetch data stored procedure and rebind the data to 2nd gridview.